# Mysql query to get total count of objects

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t3.title, 
       Count(t2.city_id) AS objectsCount 
FROM   geo_data AS t1 
       INNER JOIN object AS t2 
               ON t1.uid = t2.city_id 
                  AND t2.is_blocked = 0 
       JOIN geo_data_translation AS t3 
         ON t1.id = t3.id 
            AND t3.language_id = 'de' 
WHERE  t1.is_city = 1 
GROUP  BY name;
```

The result is:

```
+-----+------------------------------+--------------+
| id  | title                        | objectsCount |
+-----+------------------------------+--------------+
| 404 | Achim                        |            1 |
|  85 | Ahrensburg                   |            3 |
| 305 | Ahrensfelde                  |            2 |
| 471 | Aichach                      |            1 |
| 377 | Alfeld (Leine)               |            1 |
| 373 | Algermissen                  |            2 |
| 465 | Allershausen                 |            1 |
| 525 | Alsheim                      |            1 |
| 152 | Altenmoor                    |            1 |
| 482 | Anzing                       |            1 |
| 518 | Armsheim                     |            3 |
| 562 | Arnsdorf                     |            1 |
| 109 | Artlenburg                   |            1 |
| 476 | Aschheim                     |            1 |
| 224 | Asendorf                     |            1 |
| 436 | Augusta                      |            1 |
| 447 | Aystetten                    |            1 |
| 360 | Banteln                      |            1 |
```

What we see is a list of cities with their nomber of objects. 
The city of Achim  has 1 object, and Ahrensburg has 3 objects and so on

What I want to do is to also get a total object count for all listed cities.
Thanks

Comment: Try removing the GROUP BY altogether and changing the SELECT to "SELECT COUNT(t2.city_id)"

Comment: Given this intermediate result, what would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.title,sum(t1.objectscount)as 'total_count' from table1 t1 
group by t1.title
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS objectsCount 
FROM
    geo_data AS t1 
    INNER JOIN object AS t2 
        ON  t1.uid         = t2.city_id 
        AND t2.is_blocked  = 0 
    INNER JOIN geo_data_translation AS t3 
        ON  t1.id          = t3.id 
        AND t3.language_id = 'de' 
WHERE
    t1.is_city = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name,
       t1.id, 
       t3.title, 
       Count(t2.city_id) AS objectsCount 
FROM   geo_data AS t1 
       INNER JOIN object AS t2 
               ON t1.uid = t2.city_id 
                  AND t2.is_blocked = 0 
       JOIN geo_data_translation AS t3 
         ON t1.id = t3.id 
            AND t3.language_id = 'de' 
WHERE  t1.is_city = 1 
GROUP  BY name WITH ROLLUP;
```

The `WITH ROLLUP` option will make it add an extra row with `name = NULL`, containing the total of all the counts.

See the documentation of [GROUP BY Modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)